# Get initials from name except from last name - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I used the following code to extract initials and work fines, but it extracts last name initial as well.

```js
String.prototype.getInitials = function(glue) {
  if (typeof glue == "undefined") {
    var glue = true;
  }
  var initials = this.replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, "").match(/\b\w/g);
  if (glue) {
    return initials.join('.');
  }
  return initials;
};
console.log("first middle last".getInitials());
```

How to remove last letter please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the last index while joining. Also added some safety check using optional chaining so it doesn't return undefined.

```js
String.prototype.getInitials = function(glue) {
  if (typeof glue == "undefined") {
    var glue = true;
  }

  var initials = this.replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, "").match(/\b\w/g)?.slice(0, -1) ?? [];

  if (glue) {
    return initials.join('.') ?? "";
  }

  return initials;
};

console.log("my name is".getInitials());
```

Comment: An edit was made, please check that out. Also, if you think the solution is correct you can mark it as correct :)

Comment: This won't omit it if `glue` is `false`. I'd `slice` it before: `var initials = this.replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, "").match(/\b\w/g)?.slice(0,-1) ?? [];

  if (glue) {
    return initials.join('.');
  }

  return initials;`

Comment: You are right @FZs, honestly I didn't take a look into other lines of codes at all. Will adapt it.